# iOS, How to get list of parent classes with its children in Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have the table Users and the table Posts.

```
---Users---
id
name

---Posts---
id
text
User
```

How do I get the list of users, including the posts? I know how to get the list of posts with the users, because the pointer of the user is in that table. But the users does not have any pointers to posts.

Comment: You mean all the posts for a specified user? And in what language?

Comment: Sorry, it's objective-C.. And it's not for a specified user.. I want all users with their posts..

Answer (score 0):

What you want will be a lot of requests. You can easily query for (and paginate) the users. Then, for each user, you need to make another (paginated) request to find `Post`s with a pointer to that user. For that use `whereKey:equalTo:` with the bame of the user column on the `Post` and the current user instance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a list of users already, and need to get all of their posts? If so, use the `whereKey:containedIn:` method.  You can also create a query on users that pulls all the users you want to pull the posts for, and then rather than running the query, you create a second query on your posts objects and use `whereKey:matchesQuery:` which means that the object referenced in the Key is an object that would be returned by the query you pass in.  So it'll return all the posts relevant to the users that would be returned from the initial query.

When you run this query, you may want to look into the query.each() method as an alternative to query.find().  query.find() is limited to 1000 results, query.each goes through every single result. This could be a problem when you scale, though, as cloud methods have a 15 second timer, and before/after save triggers have a 3 second timer.